# Can't find Python.h compiling C program in macOS

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a simple program on C called **example.c** which uses Python.h
I know a way to compile it using CMake (and it really works!). You can check my CMakeLists.txt at the end.

But I'd like to learn to compile it using standard clang. I tried

```
gcc -std=c11 -I /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin example.c
```

as far as

```
gcc -std=c11 -I /usr/local/bin example.c
```

In both ways I get

```
example.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
```

My *CMakeLists.txt* as promised:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS "ON")

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11 -g -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-unused-result")

project(example)
set(SOURCES example.c)

find_package(PythonLibs 3.8 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(example ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: Does the directory `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8` contain a file named `Python.h`? (Hint: nope, it's not even a directory)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I miss typed. But it still doesn’t solve my problem